# How to pass a local variable to a callback while getting something returned by the calling function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, winjs, self-invoking-function

I have a problem with a async callback in a loop. I call a asynchronous function on one of Window's  file objects to get further informations about it (`getImagePropertiesAsync()`) and save these to a database to make further access faster. I need the values that are returned by that functions as well as the value `i` had when I called `getImagePropertiesAsync()`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < picsGiven.length; i++) {
  picsGiven[i].properties.getImagePropertiesAsync().then(function(prop){
    settings.values["geoLat" + i2] = props.latitude;
    settings.values["geoLon" + i2] = props.longitude;
    settings.values["geoDate" + i2] = props.dateTaken;
    i2++;
  })
}
```

Because of the asynchronous execution, the pairs three values got saved in the wrong order. I already worried about that problem by the time I was writing that. Next try.

```
for (var i = 0; i < picsGiven.length; i++) {
  picsGiven[i].properties.getImagePropertiesAsync().then((function(prop, i2){
    settings.values["geoLat" + i2] = props.latitude;
    settings.values["geoLon" + i2] = props.longitude;
    settings.values["geoDate" + i2] = props.dateTaken;
  })(undefined, i))
}
```

Now, I got `i` correctly, but `props` is undefined. (Logically).

How can I possibly get `i` correctly while preserving `props`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Untested) something like this:

```
function mk_handleImagePropertiesAsync(ival) {
  return function(prop) {
    settings.values["geoLat" + ival] = prop.latitude;
    settings.values["geoLon" + ival] = prop.longitude;
    settings.values["geoDate" + ival] = prop.dateTaken;
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < picsGiven.length; i++) {
  picsGiven[i]
    .properties
    .getImagePropertiesAsync()
    .then(mk_handleImagePropertiesAsync(i));
}
```

Scoping issue! The for-loop does not introduce a new block-scope as in C/C++. The inline function in your loop will always get the same value of i2 (its initial value!)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I'm trying now, but running this might take some time...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < picsGiven.length; i++) {
       picsGiven[i].properties.getImagePropertiesAsync().then(function(i){
           return function(prop){
               //your code  here you can use i
           }
       }(i));
    }
```